# Storing directly to file in android?

Tags: android, file-handling, android-external-storage

I have been working on a child monitoring app and i dont know as to how to store/write fetched call logs directly into a file in external/internal storage

Comment: This is a very broad question. Please be more specific.

Comment: sir how can we store some data directly to file in android

Comment: Do you realize that's not a "facing a problem" situation rather than an "I have no idea where to start looking"? Here a guide for SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well as commented in your question , this is a very broad question but take a look at this google developer link

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

it will give you a clarity for your question and yo'll get your answer as well with detailed code

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You should work with file URI to avoid android security problems. This way you are able to work with this files in other applications (grant permissions to them)

First of all, put this into your android-manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/
```

Then you need to define file provider inside application tag:

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.yourpackagename.yourapp"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

file_path resource should looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="YourAppCacheStorage"
        path="YourAppCacheStorage"/>
</paths>
```

Then you will be able to get your files URI whenever you are.

```
public Uri getUriForFile(File file, Context context) {
                final Uri uriForFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                            context.getString(R.string.file_provider_authority),
                            file);
                return uriForFile;
}
```

this uri can be used to open Input\Output streams to your files.

```
InputStream inputStream = this.context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

You can get more information there: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html